# Short phrase for "... for the first time in five years."

Tags: phrases, abbreviations, speech

When I did something for the first time in five (or ten, several, etc...) years, 
is there any phrase to describe the same situation shortly?

Sometimes I feel **"... for the first time in five years"** is too much and I want to use shorter/lighter phrase like *for ages*.
I can say **"It's been five years since I did it last time"**, but still long.

I would appreciate it if you tell me some words or phrases.

Thanks,

Comment: Well, you could always say "I did my pentannual planting of penta annuals."

Comment: For the 10 years you mention: "I haven't done this for a decade." But you don't really hear people say that. Is the *exact* time span so important? If so, then "I haven't done this since 2013" or other date. Or "I haven't done this since college."

Comment: But it says precisely what you want to say, clearly and simply (no cumbersome long words), and with a pleasant rhythm.  It says exactly what you want to say.

Comment: If you are expressing that a thing you are currently doing or about to do is a thing that you have n't done for 5 years, the 'first/last time' part is unnecessary. Rather than 'It is the first time in 5 years that I've eaten frogs' legs', you can just say 'I haven't eaten frogs' legs for 5 years.', or instead of 'it's been 5 years since I ate eggs last time', 'It's been 5 years since I ate eggs' of 'its been 5 years since I last ate eggs'. No meaning is lost by omitting 'time' or 'last time'.

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you for your answers! It helps me a lot! @Spagirl, no meaning is lost omitting "time" or "last time" is great information for me. Thanks.